# which algorithm used by ubuntu or linux for file or folder searching in directory

Tags: package-management

I have a project in my college to search file or folder using the Linux or Ubuntu algorithm. I have to adapt it for mac and windows.

Which algorithm does ubuntu use?
or what these all OS use to search any file folder in directory.....

Comment: This does not make sense what are you searching for ? What do you mean by algorithm for linux but also windows and mac ? That is not something linux specific.

Comment: To the downvoters, this is a perfectly acceptable question (admitted, after the edit).

Comment: then what these Operating System use to search file or folder..... I don't know any thing about it..

Comment: Its really a brainstorm question @markkirby

Comment: You should really provide all the research you did so far. Asking the question here should *follow* doing your own research.

Comment: Your re-edit did not make the question any clearer. Please check your phrasing and english.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a project in my college to search file or folder using the Linux or Ubuntu algorithm. I have to adapt it for mac and windows.
>
> Which algorithm does ubuntu use?

An [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) is something abstract, not bound to an OS and neither to a programming language.
The aforementioned libcolumbus is a [library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) that implements the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2012/12/03/introducing-libcolumbus-a-fast-online-approximate-matching-library/).

Comment: Agreed Jan. I metonymically referred to the implementation as the algorithm, but I like your distinction.

Answer (score 3):

I think the algorithm is called libcolumbus.

More about it can be found on the creator's blog:  [Introducing libcolumbus, a fast online approximate matching library](http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2012/12/03/introducing-libcolumbus-a-fast-online-approximate-matching-library/)